# NDK Debug in Android Studio no longer works after updating from Gradle tools 2.2.3 to 2.3.1 and the distribution url from 2.14.1 to 3.3-all

Tags: android, android-ndk

I can demonstrably roll back those versions to 2.2.3/2.14.1 and debug native code no problem. If I move those numbers back up, it fails -- the code compiles and runs alright, but there's no native breakpoints being hit.

Was there anything new added in that new Gradle version that I need to account for now?